# Как конвертировать JPEG/PNG файл в SVG?

Tags: svg, php, javascript, jpeg, png

Нужно при помощи PHP/JS либо конвертировать существующий JPEG/PNG-файл в SVG, либо создать новый SVG из JPEG/PNG-файла.

Comment: А зачем вам это?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно делать векторизацию. В общем случае, это нетривиальная задача.

- http://corel.demiart.ru/book12/Glava_17/Index08.htm
- http://habrahabr.ru/post/68323/

Comment: Не, ну можно еще битмап растровый включить в SVG (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6250418/409863)